# ORACLE SQL ORA-24344 - counting attendance function error

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Hey guys I have a problem,
I want to create a function in ORACLE which will count number of attendance (how many subject has enrolled one student). Could you give me a tip I don't know if my syntax is even okay?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION num_of_attendance (id_student IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS total_number_of_attendance NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN 
    WITH attendance AS
    (
        SELECT id_student, code_course, COUNT(DISTINCT code_subject)
        FROM STUDENT NATURAL INNER JOIN attendance NATURAL INNER JOIN course NATURAL INNER JOIN course_subject NATURAL INNER JOIN subject
    );
    RETURN total_number_of_attendance;
END;
/
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statements of the tables, `INSERT` statements with sample data and the desired result as tabular text.

Comment: A `with` clause needs a `select` after it, it can't be just `with x as (select y from z);` But you don't need any `with` clause anyway, just `select count(whatever) into your variable from ...`

Comment: Natural joins are usually not a good approach as they blindly match any common column names, so if you add a `DESCRIPTION` column to both `COURSE` and `SUBJECT`, for example, your natural joins will fail. It's best to specify the join columns explicitly. (Also `inner` and `outer` keywords are optional. Include them if you like, but they don't add any value.)

Answer (score 1):

First try to run the SQL statement outside the function.

Does this SQL statement runs without error ?

```
WITH attendance AS
    (
        SELECT id_student, code_course, COUNT(DISTINCT code_subject)
        FROM STUDENT NATURAL INNER JOIN attendance NATURAL INNER JOIN course NATURAL INNER JOIN course_subject NATURAL INNER JOIN subject
    );
```

Second, if you need to return a value from a function you need to store this value using `INTO variable` clause with this general syntax:

```
SELECT ... INTO variable FROM ... WHERE ...
```